# What is my MQTT Ip Adress?

Tags: mqtt

I installed the [Mosquitto MQTT](https://mosquitto.org) on my Pi and I want to test it on my Windows via Putty.

What is my MQTT server **IP address and port** ?

I tried `ifconfig` but it shows:

```
 inet addr : as hex like fe80::465d.... etc.
```

Comment: Which MQTT (mosquito) or some other implementation? can you post your `/etc/network/interface` file

Comment: Sorry i forgot it. Its mosquitto

Comment: I think you do not have any IP address, your server is binded on the `localhost` something like `127.0.0.1` or `::1`. the `fe80::` is your IPv6 Link-Local Address.

Comment: So what should i enter to puttys ip area ?

Comment: add the IP address of the Pi in your `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` file and it will be a server with that particular IP

Answer (score 6):

According to the `man` page for [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html)
It is dominated by a **Configuration file** which is `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`.

According to the `man` page for the [`mosquitto.conf`](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html):

> bind_address *address*
>
> Listen for incoming network connections on the specified IP address/hostname only. This is useful to restrict access to certain network interfaces. To restrict access to mosquitto to the local host only, use "bind_address localhost". This only applies to the default listener. Use the listener variable to control other listeners.
>
> listener port [bind address/host]
>
> Listen for incoming network connection on the specified port. A second optional argument allows the listener to be bound to a specific ip address/hostname. If this variable is used and neither the global bind_address nor port options are used then the default listener will not be started.
>
> The bind address/host option allows this listener to be bound to a specific IP address by passing an IP address or hostname. For websockets listeners, it is only possible to pass an IP address here.

Hence your current IP address is the `localhost` IP address generally `127.0.0.1` for IPv4 and or `::1` for IPv6. This can be seen from `ifconfig lo`.

Default port number for `mosquitto` is **1883** according to the [`man` page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html)

`fe80::` addresses are [**IPv6 Link-Local Addresses**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) which exist for each IPv6 enabled device on your Pi.

It is recommended to change the IP address and port values in your `mosquitto.conf` for your desired functionality and restart `mosquitto` again:

```
 /etc/init.d/mosquitto restart
```

Comment: I added "bind_address 192.168.1.29" and "listener port[192.168.1.29/1883]" to mosquitto.conf file . I restarted service and when i try to sub and pub to topic it says "Error:Connection refused" .

Comment: Okay i changed ssh settings to enabled in preferences/interfaces menu. It's solved. Also added pi@ before ip address . Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you think the answer is what you wanted then accept it for future reference.